# validate names in kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin

My problem is the user insert a name like "Jon Snow" and I don't know how to validate with a function if the names first char is upper case and if they are spare by a space

```
fun checkName(nome:String):Boolean{
    if (name[0].isUpperCase()){
        var count=0
        //if (nome)
        do {
            count++

        }while (name[count]==' ')
        var charAfterSpace:Char=nome[count]+1
        when(charAfterSpace.isUpperCase()){
           false->return false
            //else->return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Split](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) the string then check if [all](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html) the elements match the criteria:

```
fun checkName(name: String): Boolean =
    name.split(' ').all { it[0].isUpperCase() }
```

If double-spaces might be an issue, then first check to make sure it's not empty:

```
fun checkName(name: String): Boolean =
    name.split(' ').all { !it.isEmpty() && it[0].isUpperCase() }
```

Comment: It works but i can't use split. I just have to use if, when, do While and while :(