# How do I change the for loop to a while loop and not use .lastindex in this function?

Tags: kotlin

I have already tried changing but the function stops working correctly.

```kotlin
fun checkName(name: String): Boolean {
    val CAPS = 'A'..'Z'
    val LOWER = 'a'..'z'
    var spaces = 0
    var capsCheck = true
    for (char in name) {
        if (spaces > 1) return false
        else if (char == ' ') { spaces++; capsCheck = true }
        else if (capsCheck) if (char !in CAPS) return false else capsCheck = false
        else if (char !in LOWER) return false
    }
    if (spaces != 1 || name[name.lastIndex] == ' ') return false 

    return true
}
```

Comment: Can someone explain to me the [large](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65162915/5923139) [amounts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65242579/5923139) of [`checkName`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65267505/5923139) posts (without using `split` or `indexOf`) from new contributors lately?

Comment: @Aplet123 I answered this guy yesterday on discord still he asked the same question here https://imgur.com/O75wEHx, voting for low quality and should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of a running index and use the definition of `name.lastIndex` instead (`name.length - 1`):

```kotlin
fun checkName(name: String): Boolean {
    val CAPS = 'A'..'Z'
    val LOWER = 'a'..'z'
    var spaces = 0
    var capsCheck = true
    var i = 0
    while (i < name.length) {
        val char = name[i]
        if (spaces > 1) return false
        else if (char == ' ') { spaces++; capsCheck = true }
        else if (capsCheck) if (char !in CAPS) return false else capsCheck = false
        else if (char !in LOWER) return false
        i += 1
    }
    if (spaces != 1 || name[name.length - 1] == ' ') return false 

    return true
}
```